# Remove child element based on some attribute criteria of child element xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove the child element on the bases of the value of an id attribute. If there is no value in id attribute or there is no id attribute at all in contentblock tag then just remove the  element and parent element will remain same if present. Also if content block is direct child of root and that content block doesn't have value in id attribute or there is no id attribute then remove that element also.

Example:

```
<root>
 <div>
   <contentblock class="align-center" id="" />
</div>
 <p>
   <contentblock class="align-center" />
</p>
 <h2>
   <contentblock class="align-center" id="623a7a1f87dd1975ce084ac7"/>
</h2>
<contentblock class="align-center" id=""/>
<contentblock class="align-center" id="623a7a1f87dd1975ce084ac7"/>
<contentblock class="align-center"/>
</root>
```

Expected Result:

```
<root>
 <div>
 </div>
 <p>
</p>
 <h2>
   <contentblock class="align-center" id="623a7a1f87dd1975ce084ac7"/>
</h2>
<contentblock class="align-center" id="623a7a1f87dd1975ce084ac7"/>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

What i tried but didn't give the expected result:

```
 <!--<xsl:template match="contentblock[not(parent::root)] | contentblock[(parent::root)]">-->
        <!--<xsl:choose>-->
    <!--      <xsl:if test="contentblock/@id[string-length(.) =0]">-->
    <!--            <xsl:apply-templates/>-->
    <!--      </xsl:if>-->
        <!--</xsl:choose>-->
    <!--</xsl:template>-->
```

Another try:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contentblock] | p[descendant::contentblock] | h2[descendant::contentblock] | h3[descendant::contentblock]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contentblock[@id!='']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contentblock[@id=''] | contentblock[not(@id)]">
        <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/></xsl:copy>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

I can't match  `<xsl:template match="contentblock[not(parent::root)]">` as it performs the transformation on content block element itself which gives  me different result. And also above solution does not work when i get the xml like this. When contentblock have multiple level parents like here it's p and span are parents of contentblock.

```
 <p id="5c3692c8af8fe1f061518abc">
      <span bulb-font-face="museo-sans, sans-serif">
         <contentblock class="align-center block-full-width" id="5c3686fdcb7de304cd51696f" />
      </span>
   </p>
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I added in my question about what i tried.

Comment: Start by reading how to use a xsl:choose. It cannot contain a child xsl:if

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I updated one more try in my question but that is not a god way of doing because i don't know how many different parents i will get for my contentblock

Answer (score 0):

This template would match `contentblock` elements with an `id` attribute that has some value:

```
<xsl:template match="contentblock[@id!='']"/>
```

You would have to apply this template to all relevant `contentblock` elements, and in the template you would have to return whatever you want to return, like

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

Comment: which match would work for the contentblock tag which doesnot have id attribute at all?

Comment: "contentblock[@id=''] | contentblock[not(@id)]" This match looks good for my scenerio.

Comment: even better: contentblock[not(@id != '')]